# How to show that $\Omega_{c}=\left\{x \in \mathbb R^{n}: V(x) \leq c\right\}$ is compact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, compactness, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Consider an ODE system
$$\dot{x}=f(x),$$
having a candidate Lypunov function, which satisfies $V(x)\geq0$, $V(0)=0$, and $\dot{V}(x)\leq0$.

How to show that the set
$$\Omega_{c}=\left\{x \in \mathbb R^{n}: V(x) \leq c\right\}$$ is compact?

Since $V(x)$ is a radially unbounded function, such that $\Omega_{c}$ must have an upper bound, $0$ will be the lower bound of the set.

What about the closed property? We know this set must contain the lower boundary $0$, how do we know whether this set contains an upper boundary?

Comment: if $V$ is continuous, then $\Omega_c = V^{-1 }(-\infty,c])$

Comment: @dawen are you trying to prove the theorem?

Comment: Hello @Vajra, I am not trying to prove anything. This is actually originated from Lasalle's theorem. An ODE book tells this set $\Omega_{c}$ is invariant and compact. I can understand the invariant property. But still trying to figure why it is compact.

Comment: $\Omega_c = V^{-1}(-\infty,c]$ is bounded since $V$ is continuous. It is not necessarily bounded with your assumptions (indeed $f = V = 0$ gives $\Omega_c = \mathbb R^n$)

Comment: @SolubleFish But is $V^{-1}$ a continous function?

Comment: @dawen $V^{-1}$ does not necessarily exist, since $V$ has no reason to be bijective. The notation $V^{-1}(A)$ denotes the preimage of $A$ by $V$, and for a continuous function $V$ and a closed set $A$, it is closed. It can be always defined, even if $V^{-1}$ does not exist as a reciprocal function.

Comment: As Solublefish pointed out, you are likely missing some assumptions on $V$. As or now you cannot show that $\Omega _c$ is compact.

Comment: Your question is unclear: (1) $\dot{V}(x)$ (usually denoted $grad V(x)$) is a vector, not a number, so it does not have a sign; (2) one cannot say that a subset of $R^n$ has an "upper bound" (or a lower bound which you claim is $0$); (3) when you say that $V$ is "radially bounded" (this terminology), do you mean that it is "not radially unbounded"? Or is it just a typo and you mean "radially unbounded"?  The latter would indeed imply compactness of $\Omega_c$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan OP missed some important background setup. $V:R^n \to R$ and $\dot{V}(x) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f(x) $. But like you, I don't understand what he meant by upper bound.

Comment: @Hermis14: Ah, I see, I should have guessed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $c > 0$. We have to show that $\Omega_c$ is closed and bounded.

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

1. Since $V$ is differentiable, $V:\R^n \to \R$ is continuous. Therefore, $\Omega_c$ is closed.
2. From the definition of [radial unboundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radially_unbounded_function)
   $$
   \forall c > 0: \exists r > 0: \forall x \in \R^n : (||x|| > r \Rightarrow V(x) > c)
   $$
   where the contrapositive of the conditional is
   $$
   V(x) \le c \Rightarrow ||x|| \le r
   $$
   Therefore, $\Omega_c$ is bounded.